# Newer PDFBox versions loads PDF slowly

Tags: java, pdfbox

So I am working on migrating a legacy framework using PDFBox 1.8 to PDFBox 2.x
However, I am observing a spike in the time required to load the pdf with the newer versions which almost doubles up ( 100ms on older to 200ms on newer). Now the app that we run is very sensitive to latency.

I tried searching out for the increase in latency but no luck. Just wanted help from the community to find out if there is any possible way to resolve this. The only line of code involved is -

```
PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilePath));
```

What I have already tried is-

1. Playing with the `memoryUsageSettings` and setting it to no restriction, using temp file, and a combination of both main memory and temp file.
2. Comparing the stats on a number of versions of 2.x including the latest release, all seem to be higher than the older version.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: It is possible that it got slowed from 1.8 to 2.0 because the old parser was not really correct. However it should not parse slower from 2.0.0 to 2.0.20. Please share your file.

Comment: Just to reiterate latency increases from 1.8 to 2.x. There is no concern amongst 2.x versions. This behavior can be seen on any random pdf.
[link](https://www.ofx.net/downloads/OFX%202.2.pdf)

Comment: OK I tried. 1.8 loads in 1.7 seconds, 2.0.20 loads in 0.258 seconds. However I've taken care in 2.0.20 that all the one-time initializations are done before benchmarking, see also https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3988

Comment: Time goes down to 0.1 second in "ultimate speed" energy settings. (Previous benchmark was with "save energy" settings), 3 year old desktop.

Comment: Tilman, thanks for all the help but unfortunately I am just looking for loading a PDF file into a PDDocument object. There is nowhere I am concerned it to be converted to images. The Time that is taken by the following statement
`PDDocument pdfDoc = PDDocument.load((new File(pdfFilePath)));`
is my only concern.

Comment: My benchmark did not render into images. The things I mentioned will take place as part of the first parse, you should do your benchmark either at the second parse, or do the things mentioned in the issue I linked to before the first parse, when using a 2.0.* version and doing benchmarking.

Comment: Tilman, thanks for the help!!!
To Summarize - 
First parsing can be slow on 2.x version but subsequent parses will be faster. Maybe the issue is with the initial loading of classes in the classpath.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: It is the loading of fonts, initialisation of colorsspaces and some class loading.

Comment: Did my comments and the code in the issue help you get your application faster? If yes, then I would write an answer that contains the actual code that is used in PDFDebugger.

Comment: Yes Tilman, definitely your help brought great relief. Please write an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are initializations that are done when the first document is opened (fonts, colorspaces, some class loading), see also discussion in [PDFBOX-3988](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3988). Use this code (taken from PDFDebugger sources) so that they are done before the first loading.

```
// trigger premature initializations for more accurate rendering benchmarks
// See discussion in PDFBOX-3988
if (PDType1Font.COURIER.isStandard14())
{
    // Yes this is always true
    PDDeviceCMYK.INSTANCE.toRGB(new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0} );
    PDDeviceRGB.INSTANCE.toRGB(new float[] { 0, 0, 0 } );
    IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance();
    FilterFactory.INSTANCE.getFilter(COSName.FLATE_DECODE);
}
```

Comment: Perfect Tilman, there is a noticeable change in latency stats
Thanks for all the help!!!!